# How to prevents my kittens from putting nose in my coffee

Tags: drinks, pets

I tend to enjoy what are effectivly a solutions of various poisons in water (AKA tea, coffee and coffee with milk). They are not exactly healthy for my babies so I need to have constant vigilance. Is there an easy hack so I can enjoy both the presence of my kittens and a cup of coffee?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can drink your beverage out of a to-go cup designed to be covered (usually to prevent spilling hot drinks). They also make more-robust personal tumblers which serve the same purpose, but are designed to be washed and reused over and over. That should keep the family pet from sampling your morning brew.

[image] [image]

Product Search: [**Hot Cup with Lid**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=shop&q=hot++cup++with+lid)

Product Search: [**Coffee Tumbler**](https://www.google.com/search?q=coffee+tumbler&rlz=1C1SKPM_enUS444US446&oq=coffee+tumbler&aqs=chrome..69i57.3257j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=coffee+tumbler&tbm=shop)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the purpose-built cups and mugs with lids and covers, here's a **Lifehacks** answer. (inspired by a Robert Cartaino comment)
…
Place a small, light-weight saucer or "coaster" on the cup when you put it on the table or counter between sips. There's probably a perfect one sitting on the shelf in your kitchen or pantry.

This has the added benefit of keeping your drinks hotter or cooler than when left uncovered.

Answer (score 2):

Might look very odd, but how about stretching part of a pair of [clean] tights (US, pantie-hose) over the top of the cup, secured by elastic bands.

You can drink through it, but the best the cats are going to get is a lick of the damp hosiery.

Alternatively, if somewhat cynically... why not put it where they can't reach :/
...because a dollar to a bag of buttons, they'll knock it over eventually...